# Cannot remove marker on Google Map (Java)

Tags: java, android-studio, google-maps

I have an application that will update the google map marker with the latest latitude and longitude from the real time Firebase. I have a problem with removing a markers on google maps, The problem is when there is a new marker appear on the map, the previous marker couldn't be removed. I tried to use `GoogleMap.clear()` but it seem like not working. Does anyone know what caused this issue ?Thanks !

My code

```
public class PoliceMapActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    //initialize all variables
    DatabaseReference reff;
    GoogleMap map;
    String RecordId;
    Marker marker;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_police_map);
        SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.police_map);
        supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(PoliceMapActivity.this);
        //get record Id
        RecordId = getIntent().getStringExtra("recordId");
        reff = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Records");




        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while (isInterrupted()) {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                // update onmapready()
                                if (supportMapFragment != null) {
                                    supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(PoliceMapActivity.this);
                                    if (marker != null) {
                                        map.clear();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        };
        thread.start();

    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        map.clear();

        final DatabaseReference finalreff = reff.child(RecordId);
        finalreff.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    
                Double lat = (Double) snapshot.child("latitude").getValue();
                Double lon = (Double) snapshot.child("longitude").getValue();
                String name = snapshot.child("Fullname").getValue().toString();
                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lon);
                googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(getIntent().getStringExtra(name)));
                googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 18));


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });



    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may have invoked map.clear() on a different object and not on the googleMap instance you are showing in the code.
try to invoke googleMap.clear() in the method onDataChange